# How to set the entrypoint dll dynamically in Docker image

Tags: c#, docker, dockerfile

We want to use a single `Dockerfile` for a few different projects.

The projects structure is the same and the only different as far as the Dockerfile concerns is the entrypoint `dll`.

Here is how one of those `Dockerfile`s looks like:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:5.0-alpine3.13-amd64

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "dllName.dll"]
```

I thought about something like that:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:5.0-alpine3.13-amd64

ARG DLL_NAME

RUN echo "Building for $DLL_NAME"

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", $DLL_NAME]
```

And build it with: `--build-arg "DLL_NAME=dllName.dll"`
However, the `ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", $DLL_NAME]` command doesn't seem to go through when running the image:

```
/bin/sh: [dotnet,: not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RUN` instruction expects variables from environment.

Please try changing

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:5.0-alpine3.13-amd64

ARG DLL_NAME

RUN echo "Building for $DLL_NAME"

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", $DLL_NAME]
```

into

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:5.0-alpine3.13-amd64

ARG DLL_NAME
ENV DLL_NAME=$DLL_NAME

RUN echo "Building for $DLL_NAME"

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

ENTRYPOINT /bin/sh dotnet $DLL_NAME
```

Comment: That semi-worked. Apparently `ARG`s aren't expanded in `ENTRYPOINT` but `ENV`s do.  Yet, using array `[]` doesn't work either, if I change the command to `ENTRYPOINT "dotnet" $DLL_NAME_ENV` that works.
Feel free to update the answer and I'll mark it as accepted

Comment: We have been using this. The issue with this approach, as we have just found out, is that SIGTERM doesn't make it to the dotnet app.

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically specify the command to run when you launch a container.  This gets [appended to the `ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact); but, a Dockerfile `ENTRYPOINT` isn't required.  If in your Dockerfile you change `ENTRYPOINT` to `CMD`

```sh
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:5.0-alpine3.13-amd64
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
CMD ["dotnet", "dllName.dll"] # <-- not ENTRYPOINT
```

then when you launch the container you can easily override it, without rebuilding anything

```sh
docker run ... my-image \
  dotnet otherDll.dll
```

Comment: I only have the argument on build time.. If entrypoint isn't mandatory, what is it used for?

Comment: I like to use it for a pattern that does first-time setup, and then runs the `CMD` ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69729988)).  There's also a pattern of using `ENTRYPOINT` for a complete runnable command and `CMD` its arguments, but I only tend to use that when it's literally impossible for the image to run anything else (a `FROM scratch` static-Go-binary image without a shell, for example).