# Use cp in entrypoint for docker run

Tags: java, docker

There is Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:11.0.12-jre-slim
COPY target/app.jar /app.jar
COPY configs configs
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

In folder configs contains json configs for java application.
The build docker command is:

```
docker build --build-arg -f ~/IdeaProjects/app --no-cache -t app:latest
```

And the run command is:

```
docker run --entrypoint="cp configs var/opt/configs/ && java -jar app.jar" app:latest
```

Let's omit the ability to copy configs in the Dockerfile via COPY command. Unfortunately, this must be done using --entrypoint.

An error occurs when the docker run command was executed:

**docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: exec: "cp configs var/opt/configs/ && java -jar app.jar": stat cp configs var/opt/configs/ && java -jar app.jar: no such file or directory: unknown.**

Could you explain why the error occurred in this case?

Comment: It's trying to find and execute a file named `cp\ configs\ ...` including the spaces in the command file name.  You might `COPY configs ./var/opt/configs` in the Dockerfile at build time, or set the main container command to be a script that does these things instead of having to type them out at the `docker run` command line.

Comment: If you really think you need to override the command, `CMD` will be easier to override; and if you need to override the command like this, you need to manually supply a `/bin/sh -c '... && ...'` wrapper.

Comment: @DavidMaze I tried to include configs to docker container, no need in build stage. This can be done ?

Comment: I suggest starting here https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this with an *entrypoint wrapper script*.  A Dockerfile can have both an `ENTRYPOINT` and a `CMD`; if you do, [the `CMD` gets passed as arguments to the `ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact).  This means you can make the `ENTRYPOINT` a shell script that does first-time setup, then ends with `exec "$@"` to replace itself with the `CMD`.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# docker-entrypoint.sh

# copy the configuration to the right place
cp configs var/opt/configs/

# run the main container command
exec "$@"
```

In the Dockerfile, make sure to `COPY` the script in (it should be checked in to source control as executable) and set it as the `ENTRYPOINT`.

```sh
...
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh .
ENTRYPOINT ["./docker-entrypoint.sh"] # must be JSON-array syntax
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/app.jar"]      # what was previously ENTRYPOINT
```

When you run the container it's straightforward to replace the `CMD`, so you can double-check that this is doing the right thing by running an interactive shell in place of the `java` application.

```sh
docker run -v "$PWD/alt-configs:/configs" --rm -it my-image sh
```

---

If you do need to override the command like this at `docker run` time, the command you show uses `&&` to run two commands consecutively.  This needs to run a shell to be understood correctly, and in this context you need to manually provide a `/bin/sh -c` wrapper.

I would still recommend changing `ENTRYPOINT` to `CMD` in your Dockerfile; then you could run a relatively straightforward

```sh
docker run \
  ... \
  -v "$PWD/alt-configs:/configs" \
  my-image \
  /bin/sh -c 'cp configs var/opt/configs && java -jar /app.jar'
```

If you use `--entrypoint`, it only takes the first word out of this command, and it is a Docker options so it needs to come *before* the image name.  I'd recommend designing your image to avoid needing this awkward construct.

```sh
docker run \
  ... \
  -v "$PWD/alt-configs:/configs" \
  --entrypoint /bin/sh \
  my-image \
  -c 'cp configs var/opt/configs && java -jar /app.jar'
```

Your proposed command is having problems because it's trying to pass the entire command, including the embedded spaces and shell operators, as a single word, but that causes the OS-level process handling to try to look for an executable file with spaces and ampersands in the filename, hence the "no such file or directory" error.